# Select does not return rows after insert in stored procedure

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am trying to insert row into 2 tables and then do select in a stored procdure in SQL Server 2012, and for some reason I get 0 rows in php (sqlsrv) (in navicat I do get 1 row as should)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Register]
@FacebookId AS INT,
@SessionKey AS VARCHAR(255),
@Name AS NVARCHAR(255),
@Gender AS INT = 0,
@ProfilePicture AS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE FacebookId = @FacebookId)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Users(FacebookId,SessionKey) VALUES (@FacebookId,@SessionKey)
            DECLARE @Id AS INT
            SET @Id = scope_identity()
            INSERT INTO UserData(Id,Name,Gender,ProfilePicture) VALUES (scope_identity(),@Name,@Gender,@ProfilePicture)
            SELECT 1 AS success
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT 0 AS success
        END
END
```

php code:

```
        function Register($facebookId,$sessionKey,$name,$gender,$profilePicture)
        {
             return     SingleResponseRequest('Register',array('@FacebookId','@SessionKey','@Name','@Gender','@ProfilePicture'),
                                  array($facebookId,$sessionKey,$name,$gender,$profilePicture),'success');

        }


        function SingleResponseRequest($procedureName,$procedureValues,$valuesArray,$returnColumn)
        {
            require_once __DIR__ . '/Configuration/Connection.php';
            $db = new Connection();
            $values = '';

            foreach($procedureValues as $value)
                $values .= $value . ' = ? ,';

            $values = substr($values,0,strlen($values)-1);
            $query = "EXEC $procedureName $values";
            $res = $db->Query($query,$valuesArray);
            $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $res );
            echo 'rows: '. $row_count;

            if ($row_count === false)
                echo "Error in retrieving row count.";

            $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $row[$returnColumn];
        }

   public function Query($query,$params)
    {
        for($i = 0 ; $i < count($params); $i++)
        {
            $params[$i] = $this->ms_escape_string($params[$i]);
            $params[$i] = utf8_encode($params[$i]);
        }

        $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED );

        $result = sqlsrv_query($this->connection, $query, $params,$options);
        if ( $result === false )
        {
            echo "Error in statement execution.<br>";
            echo $query;
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

I do get 0 if it goes to the else condition, what could be the problem?

Comment: In the management studio of sql server output the select you have on your if clause on sql to check it that @FacebookId exists. For me that seems to be the problem. The rows are inserted on both tables?

Comment: yes, the rows are inserted successfly

Comment: Since the rows are inserted...what exactly is the question? BTW, you could make this a bit simpler by using the OUTPUT statement in your initial insert.

Comment: the problem is that the select statement is not working

Comment: Show us the code that's calling the procedure

Comment: added the code calling the procdure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I had same issue like this. I solved it .
You just place  "SET NOCOUNT ON" on your stored procedure

for example

```
CREATE procedure mysampleprocedure

AS BEGIN TRANSACTION TRANS

set nocount on
insert into sampletable(id,data) values
(
101,
'abc'
);

SELECT count(*) AS id FROM sampletable AS id;

IF @@ERROR > 0
BEGIN 
 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TRANS
 end
 ELSE
 BEGIN
 COMMIT TRANSACTION TRANS
 end
GO
```